# How to remove a column from the Posts page

Tags: posts, admin

In a previous question I asked how to add a column to the Posts page in the Administration section, and got a working answer. But now I need to know how to delete an existing column (e.g. the Date column) so that my customized Date column replaces it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
function my_manage_columns( $columns ) {
  unset($columns['date']);
  return $columns;
}

function my_column_init() {
  add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns' , 'my_manage_columns' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init' , 'my_column_init' );
```

Answer (score 1):

On a different fields it is also possible you deactivate the function of WP; as example comments and author:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'fb_deactivate_support' );
function fb_deactivate_support() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'comments' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'author' );
}
```

the post-string is for the post_type, you can also use this for all post types via:

```
foreach ( get_post_types() as $post_type ) {
    remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'comments' );
}
```

[image]