# Adding HTML tags or css classes to admin columns

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, columns, admin-css

Is it possible to add a custom class to the links in admin columns?

I'm trying to replicate the labels below.

[image: Here's an example of what I'm wanting to do.]

I'm using WP 4.1 and my CPT is using `'show_admin_column' => true` in `register_taxonomy` and I have two custom taxonomies I'd like to apply this to. I've added a color picker to the add/edit taxonomy pages if that helps with a solution--I found the answer for that [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112866/adding-colorpicker-field-to-category/113041#113041) but the usage appears to be on the front-end.

```
<?php
$cat_id = get_cat_ID('Default');
$cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");
echo $cat_data['catBG'];
?>
```

I've searched elsewhere for some kind of solution and I've found a [plugin](https://pro.emdplugins.com/demos/wp-ticket-professional-demo/) that uses labels in the admin screen but it appears they have custom HTML wrapped around their custom taxonomy links. I'd be happy with that as well if I knew where to start looking.

TIA!

On edit:
I should add that the color will be different for each label. I'd like the ability for the client to choose their own colors for each label (which is why I've added the color picker).

Comment: Rather than use the default columns WordPress adds, you can add columns manually and format them how you like. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19229/4771) for an example of adding custom columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ending up using thanks to [Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo), the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) and this post from [http://simple2kx.com/](http://simple2kx.com/customize-the-columns-in-custom-post-type-page/).

```
add_action( 'manage_issues_pm_posts_custom_column', 'my_manage_issues_pm_columns', 10, 2 );

function my_manage_issues_pm_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
global $post;
switch( $column ) {
    /* If displaying the 'issues_type' column. */
    case 'issues_type' :
        if ( $terms = get_terms( 'issues_type' ) ) {
            echo '<span>';
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
                $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
                if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
                    continue;
                }
                // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
                echo '<a class="' . $term->name . '" href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '" data-type="label">' . $term->name . '</a>';
            }

            echo '</span>';
        }
        break;
        /* Just break out of the switch statement for everything else. */
    default :
        break;
}
```

Once I get my color picker working (again), I'll add that to my code so I can assign a background color dynamically. For anyone who may be wondering, I'll probably use an inline style to set the background color where I currently have `class="' . $term->name . '"` in the href.